Unable to align text left
Widget cardText(String text) {
    return FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      child: Text(
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        text,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            color: Colors.grey,
            fontFamily: "Myriad"),
      ),
    );
  }

I want to align this textWidget left and it is coverd with a custom widget resizable widget which allow me to move it and resize it. And BoxFit.contain is the only fit that works for me.
I tried text align but it didn't work Then i tried to put align widget with alignment Centerleft at different place and the one place that worked was above the FittedBox which came with a problem
When I put Alignment widget above the fitted box, the text doesn't contain to the ResizableWidget's size, It stays the same small even if i make the widget height or width large Here,

I want it to be contained in the resizable widget
Here's the other Code
Whole Widget:
GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
                      setState(() {
                        setSelected(3);
                      });
                    },
                    child: ResizeableWidget(
                        selected: fatherNameSelected,
                        key: fatherNameKey,
                        child: cardText(fatherNameString)),
                  ),

Resizable Widget:
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ResizeableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ResizeableWidget({super.key, required this.child, required this.selected});

  final Widget child;
  bool selected;
  @override
  State<ResizeableWidget> createState() => ResizeableWidgetState();
}

const ballDiameter = 15.0;

class ResizeableWidgetState extends State<ResizeableWidget> {
  double height = 200;
  double width = 200;

  double top = 0;
  double left = 0;

  void onDrag(double dx, double dy) {
    var newHeight = height + dy;
    var newWidth = width + dx;

    setState(() {
      height = newHeight > 0 ? newHeight : 0;
      width = newWidth > 0 ? newWidth : 0;
    });
  }

  // Method to get the current position
  Offset getCurrentPosition() {
    return Offset(left, top);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          top: top,
          left: left,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: height,
            width: width,
            child: widget.child,
          ),
        ),
        // top left
        Positioned(
          top: top - ballDiameter / 2,
          left: left - ballDiameter / 2,
          child: ManipulatingBall(
            selected: widget.selected,
            onDrag: (dx, dy) {
              var mid = (dx + dy) / 2;
              var newHeight = height - 2 * mid;
              var newWidth = width - 2 * mid;

              setState(() {
                height = newHeight > 0 ? newHeight : 0;
                width = newWidth > 0 ? newWidth : 0;
                top = top + mid;
                left = left + mid;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        // top middle
        .........All 9 more Manupilating Balls Here............
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ManipulatingBall extends StatefulWidget {
  ManipulatingBall({super.key, required this.onDrag, required this.selected});

  final Function onDrag;
  bool selected;

  @override
  State<ManipulatingBall> createState() => _ManipulatingBallState();
}

class _ManipulatingBallState extends State<ManipulatingBall> {
  late double initX;
  late double initY;

  _handleDrag(details) {
    setState(() {
      initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
      initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
    });
  }

  _handleUpdate(details) {
    var dx = details.globalPosition.dx - initX;
    var dy = details.globalPosition.dy - initY;
    initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
    initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
    widget.onDrag(dx, dy);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.selected) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onPanStart: _handleDrag,
        onPanUpdate: _handleUpdate,
        child: Container(
          width: ballDiameter,
          height: ballDiameter,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.95),
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(DoubleProperty('initX', initX));
  }
}



Solved.
Somone heled solve it before it was made public
All I had to do was use FittedBox's alignment property(set it to centerleft), So the text would only take up left side and the FittedBox would take up the whole widget size
